# Android: menuItem.expandActionView() on API level < 14

Tags: android, search, menuitem, backwards-compatibility

I am implementing a search interface on my application using the search widget. I do **not** plan to support any API level < 11 (Honeycomb). In the search activity, I'd like to override `onKeyDown()` to expand the search widget when user presses the search key, and minimize it when the query text is submitted.

This is easily accomplished by calling:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    if (mSearchMenuItem != null) {
        mSearchMenuItem.expandActionView();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and when the query is submitted:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Do nothing, results for the string supplied are already shown.
            //Just collapse search widget
            mSearchMenu.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //do other stuff
             return false;
    });
```

The problem is that both collapse and expand were introduced in API level 14. As mentioned earlier I want to provide support as far back as API level 11, and I'm having trouble achieving the same functionality without calling the new API methods.

I tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    //and also called
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
}
```

but that simply didn't do anything at all (by anything I mean the searchwidget remains collapsed if it already was.

Since I am keeping the reference to the menuItem, I also tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    SearchActivity.this.onOptionsItemSelected(mSearchMenuItem);
}
```

but that didn't do anything at all either, last thing I tried was:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    searchMenu.getActionView().performClick();
    return false;
}
```

But that is no-go as well.

Any ideas on what I could do to provide the same functionality as `menuItem.collapseActionView()` and `menuItem.expandActionView()` without having to sacrifice compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have the option of differentiating your solution depending on the current running version:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
// pre honeycomb
} else {
// honeycomb and post
}
```

I know this might not be exactly what you are looking for but it might get you some of the way .

Answer (score 19):

This works on API level 10 for expanding ActionView e.g. SearchView

```
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MenuItemCompat static methods. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(menuItem);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    ...
}
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html